# Removing start of path from nginx proxy_pass

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxypass

To remove the use of ports on several of the applications running on this server, I've been using nginx's proxy_pass to do this. However, for some reason the actual url is being passed to the application. Is there a way so that it thinks `/panel` is really just `/`?

```
location /panel {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8082/;
}
```

Comment: I would use `location /panel/` with traling slash.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly, if you want to make an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to add the trailing slash

```
location /panel/ {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8082/;
}
```