# Cors issue when making request using react to nginx as a reverse proxy. Getting Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx

Code is running fine with postman but I am getting following cors error when making request to /product services using react :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/product' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

**Following is my nginx configuration)**:

```nginx
worker_processes 4;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        charset utf-8;
        location / {
            # auth_request     /auth;
            proxy_pass http://user_services:8001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /product/ {
            auth_request     /auth;
            # auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
            rewrite ^/product/(.*) /$1 break;
           
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }
            proxy_pass http://onboarding_project:8002;
        
        }

        location /notification/ {
            # auth_request     /auth;
            # auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
            rewrite ^/notification/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://notification_service:8006;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /payment/ {
        #    auth_request     /auth;
            rewrite ^/payment/(.*)$ /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://payment_microservices:8003;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:3000';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'POST, OPTIONS';  # Adjust this based on your allowed methods
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';  # Adjust the headers as needed
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:3000' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length, Content-Range' always;

        }

        location = /auth {
            internal;
            proxy_pass              http://user_services:8001/api/user/auth;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:3000' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length, Content-Range' always;
        
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to call auth first internally before making original request. I tried many things as you can see payment block but nothing works.
Following is how I am making request from client side):

```js
const response = await axios.get("http://localhost/product", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2OTU2NzYzODEsImV4cCI6MTY5NTY3OTk4MSwiYXVkIjoiNjUxMWY2YWRkN2Q4YmMyZDIyYTE0MWY2IiwiaXNzIjoiaW50ZWxsaWJsb2NrLmNvbSJ9.bJ5Qd6d9GvGnqJu5UFT8m4UTvZsEmly13QqVbMBwFz0"
        }
      });
      console.log(response, "okayyy");
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
```

**Pls look into it.
Thanks.**

Comment: The error message seems quite clear, you should not be responding with redirects for preflight (or any) API calls. If you want to remove the `/product` from the proxied URL, simply use `proxy_pass http://onboarding_project:8002/;` (note the trailing `/`). See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/725433/82530)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing start of path from nginx proxy\_pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130841/removing-start-of-path-from-nginx-proxy-pass)

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I don't see any flow issues offhand that would explain the rejection. I can offer two things, however, that may apply:

1. Are you sure you aren't getting a php failure?  You mentioned postman, which would usually make that visible to you as part of the response output.  Are there any errors in the ngnix log?
2. Some have complained that return 204 causes a rejection in some clients. Given that there is no real reason to return anything but 200 for pre-flight, have you tried that?

Comment: I have tried with 200 still getting same error.

Comment: A agree with the other comment that it certainly has something to do with an unexpected redirect.

Comment: _"Are you sure you aren't getting a php failure?"_... this isn't tagged [tag:php] and OP didn't mention it anywhere so I'm curious why you brought it up. Also, the error is browser only; Postman is not subject to the same-origin policy or its rules around preflight requests

Comment: I am using Node js .

Comment: Ah, lol.  Right.  I had just answered a php question and had it on my mind.

Comment: Anyway, nginx is known to cause a 301 in the absence of a trailing '/'.

Comment: _"nginx is known to cause a 301 in the absence of a trailing '/'"_... no, it's not. The redirect comes from `rewrite ^/product/(.*) /$1 break;`

Comment: I have just added trailing in the url of client side) const response = await axios.get("localhost/product", { headers: { Authorization: "bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2OTU2ODY3NzQsImV4cCI6MTY5NTY5MDM3NCwiYXVkIjpbIjY1MTFmNmFkZDdkOGJjMmQyMmExNDFmNiIsbnVsbF0sImlzcyI6ImludGVsbGlibG9jay5jb20ifQ.93TCI7VM7zU0evmz-pYqZmV0rUPoHBzJGMj7K5O_vd0" } }); and its started working with both case redirect as well as without redirect. Don't know what's happening.